# How can I make IOCTL calls from a driver to another driver (not in the same stack) (on windows)

Tags: kernel, driver, ioctl, irp

I want to make IOCTL call from a driver to another one which is totally different (not on the same stack)

I have checked on the net, but they only talk about how to send IOCTL to a lower driver, but it's not my case.

p.s : Both drivers are witten by me, so I can create a device object in the second driver, but how can I commmunicate with it (I cannot make DeviceIOControl calls from kernel)

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't differ much from sending IOCTLs from the userland. Just use [ZwOpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to your device and [ZwDeviceIoControlFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566441%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send IOCTLs. And don't forget to set OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE attribute for the handle.